# replacing content on pages that use ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a extension for a fb game that adds some extra info to popup boxes, hides some useless information and run some timers so you can see how long till you have to do something even if you are not on the game page.
My problem is that a while back they went over to using ajax to change between pages and I am wondering if I am using the right approach to handle this.
I run a setInterval that checks if I am on a page where i want to add/remove soemting and i havent done it yet, if this is true I do my stuff, the code looks something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    if($(selector for some element I am looking for).length > 0 && $(selector for some item I add).length == 0) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
setInterval("myFunction()",1000);
```

Is this the right way of handling ajax page change from an content script in an extension?
If so is there a better way to see if I am on the right page or if i have added to this page already other than doing a selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) jquery plugin to catch when new element is created on a page:

```
$("#ajax-element").livequery(function({
    //ajax-element is created
});
```

You can also listen to `DOMSubtreeModified` event which fires when DOM changes:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
    //something has changed, possibly ajax-element was added
});
```

There are also more specific `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` and `DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument` events.